# How to Complete a Function to Calculate Tips for an Array of Bills in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm working on a JavaScript function to calculate tips based on the total amount of a bill. The goal is to calculate a 15% tip for bills between 50 and 100 units (inclusive), and a 20% tip for all other bills. After calculating the tips, I want to store them in an array corresponding to a predefined array of bill amounts. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply my calculateTip function to each bill in my array of bills and then store the resulting tips in another array.

Here is the code so far:

```
function calculateTip(bill) {
    if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 100) {
        return bill * 0.15;
    } else {
        return bill * 0.20;
    }
}

const bills = [125, 555, 44];
const tips = [];
```

Comment: `const tips = bills.map(calculateTip)`  See [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You've already implemented the logic to calculate the tip based on the amount. Your last hurdle is to implement a loop to iterate over the amounts in `bills`, run the calculation and store the result in `tips`.

To do that you can use a `for` loop, along with the `push()` method, like this:

```js
function calculateTip(bill) {
  if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 100) {
    return bill * 0.15;
  } else {
    return bill * 0.20;
  }
}

const bills = [125, 555, 44];
const tips = [];

for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
  tips.push(calculateTip(bills[i]));
}

console.log(tips);
```

If you wanted to take this a step further, the `calculateTip()` method can be simplified to a one-liner, and you can use the `map()` method to iterate through the values array, and create a new array with the outputs:

```js
const calculateTip = bill => bill * (bill >= 50 && bill <= 100 ? 0.15 : 0.2);
const bills = [125, 555, 44];
const tips = bills.map(calculateTip);

console.log(tips);
```